# getting the value from dictionary

Tags: objective-c

```
stRs232Timer* pEvent;
pEvent = (stRs232Timer*)[m_cAppIdMap objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds]];
```

I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.Why is it so?

EDITED:

```
-(BOOL)createTimer
{
    stRs232Timer*   pEvent = malloc(sizeof(stRs232Timer));

    pEvent->bPersistent = YES;                              // setup timer structure
    //pEvent->pStack      = pStack;
    pEvent->wAppTimerId = 95;
    pEvent->uPeriod     = 50;
    pEvent->bStopped    = NO;
    pEvent->uExpirationTime = 10;

    NSLog(@"bPersistent:%d",pEvent->bPersistent);
    NSLog(@"wAppTimerId:%d",pEvent->wAppTimerId);
    NSLog(@"uPeriod:%d",pEvent->uPeriod);
    NSLog(@"bStopped:%d",pEvent->bStopped);


    NSData* myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)pEvent length:sizeof(stRs232Timer*)];

    wTimerId = 99;
    pEvent->uPeriod = 51;
    myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)pEvent length:sizeof(stRs232Timer*)];
    [m_cAppIdMap setObject:myData forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerId]];
    wTimerId = 96;
    pEvent->uPeriod = 52;
    myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)pEvent length:sizeof(stRs232Timer*)];
    [m_cAppIdMap setObject:myData forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerId]];
    wTimerId = 97;
    pEvent->uPeriod = 53;
    myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)pEvent length:sizeof(stRs232Timer*)];
    [m_cAppIdMap setObject:myData forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerId]];
    wTimerId = 98;
    pEvent->uPeriod = 54;
    myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)pEvent length:sizeof(stRs232Timer*)];
    [m_cAppIdMap setObject:myData forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerId]];
    wTimerId = 95;
    pEvent->uPeriod = 55;
    myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(void*)pEvent length:sizeof(stRs232Timer*)];
    [m_cAppIdMap setObject:myData forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerId]];

    NSLog(@"The dictionary count now is:%d",[m_cAppIdMap count]);
    NSLog(@"The dictionary values now is:");
    NSLog(@"%@",m_cAppIdMap);


    [m_cPendingEventList addObject:myData];
    NSLog(@"EventList:%@",m_cPendingEventList);

    [self StopTimer:99];

return YES;
}

-(BOOL)StopTimer:(unsigned short)wTimerIds
{
    NSLog(@"Into the StopTimer!!");
    stRs232Timer* pEvent;
    BOOL bReturn = NO;
    pEvent = (stRs232Timer*)[m_cAppIdMap objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds]];

    if ([theLock tryLock]) {
        int cnts = [m_cAppIdMap count];
        NSLog(@"The count is:%d",cnts);
           if(pEvent!=nil)
            {
                pEvent->bStopped = YES;
                [m_cAppIdMap removeObjectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds]];
                bReturn = YES;
            }
    }
    NSLog(@"My Dictionary value now is:%@",m_cAppIdMap);
    [theLock unlock];
    return bReturn;
}
```

I debugged the code to see where its causing this exception.[m_cAppIdMap removeObjectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds]];
inside the stopTimer.It comes out.

stRs232Timer is a pointer to the structure that is stored onto the NSDictionary as an NSObject using NSData.

Comment: What type is wTimerIds  and m_cAppIdMap ?

Comment: wTimerIds is unsigned short and m_cAppIdMap is NSDictionary object

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it's that code that's crashing? If `wTimerIds` is an unsigned short, then the dictionary will return `nil` if the key doesn't exist. Even if the dictionary is not defined, sending a message to a `nil` object is valid and so would not cause a crash.

Therefore, I think either:
1. The crash is elsewhere
2. `wTimerIds` is not an unsigned short

Answer (score 2):

`m_cAppIdMap` may have been released prematurely. You can run the Profiler (use the Zombies tool) and if that is the case you will get an error saying that a message has been sent to a released object when it tries to call objectForKey

Comment: @jjwchoy:Its not showing anything.I went into the zombies..time profiler and checked..

Comment: If i remove the NSAutoreleasePool in the main function i'm getting error messages like "*** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x1001111c0 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking".

Comment: removing the autorelease pool is a bad idea - if you have no autorelease pools then `autorelease` will not work and you will get a bunch of memory leaks. Can you show the code you use to create the dictionary?

Comment: @Alvin, where do you initialise m_cAppIdMap. I still suspect that you are releasing this too early. Make sure you don't have more `release` (or `autorelease`) calls then `alloc` and `retain` combined.

Comment: @jjwchowy:I am intialising it in the init method(constructor) and i'm not calling any release or retain.